# How to replace Date Time in a String with Empty String using C#?

Tags: c#, replace, string

I have string Like

```
Print date :6/19/2013 11:31:55 AM
```

Replace this one with Empty String

```
Print date : (String.Empty)
```

Answer should be

```
Print date :
```

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: *Replace this one...* Which one?

Comment: Just return *Print date : *

Comment: `string str = "Print date :"` is this a real question?

Comment: `str = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf(":") + 1);`

Comment: @Alireza Yes just Return Print Date:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it is acceptable but this will also work for invalid date or time values like 55:55:55

```
string input = "Print date :6/19/2013 11:31:55 AM ";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} \d\d:\d\d:\d\d [AP]M", "");
```

Comment: I use this one it help me a lot....,

Answer (score 2):

Using the IndexOf to retrieve the position of the ":" and then extracting everything before the found pos plus one character

```
string line = "Print date :6/19/2013 11:31:55 AM";
int pos = line.IndexOf(':');
if(pos >= 0)
{
    line = line.Substring(0, pos + 1);
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```